# How to move spinner in LinearLayout to right?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I have code like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Points to win"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently it looks like that:

[image]

I would like to move Spinner to the right side of the LinearLayout. I tried to use:

```
android:gravity="right"
```

and

```
android:gravity="end"
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

and

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

but it didn't help. Is there any other option to move it to the right? 
What's also important I want to keep parent layout as Linear (oriented vertically) and current layout as Linear (oriented horizontally).

Comment: You can use `layout_weight="1" ` in your `TextView`

Comment: Use FrameLayout instead if you set `android:layout_gravity="right"` to Spinner

Comment: @ChiragSavsani, what you said is veeery interesting! Nevertheless I would like to know if there's any way to keep this spinner as small as possible and only move it to the right.

Comment: @withparadox2, like I said, I want to keep it as LinearLayout.

Comment: @Tomas can you try the code which i have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Tomas See my answer below

Comment: @Tomas . Change the LinearLayout width to WrapContent and add the following attributes to it.android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

Comment: @Tomas You can use like this : `layout_width = "0dp" layout_weight="1"` in the TextView. Try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use `RelativeLayout` to this logic:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Points to win"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

By parent alignments properties (i.e. layout_alignParentLeft, layout_alignParentRight) you can place components to prefered place

Answer (score 1):

Hey check this code.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Points to win"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help.Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

please use relative layout instead of linear layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Points to win"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `layout_width` of Spinner and set `layout_weight` to TextView.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Points to win"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this its your code i have updated a bit.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Points to win"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

here is the screenshot it works well as

http://screencast.com/t/kD5y6PlVi

Answer (score 1):

Just channge following changes in your code.

In `TextView`

```
layout_width="0dp" 
layout_weight="1"
```

**See Code.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Points to win"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner$_points_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your LinearLayout to the following:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforPRICE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
```